# Colab not recognizing local gpu

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Im trying to train a Neural Network that I wrote, but it seems that colab is not recognizing the gtx 1050 on my laptop. I can't use their cloud GPU's for this task, because I run into memory constraints

```py
print(cuda.is_available())
```

is returning False

Comment: Since you did not mentioned in the question, I have to ask: Have you configured local runtimes ? https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html Did it report any error?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you gotta select the local runtime accelerator to use GPUs or TPUs, go to `Runtime` then `Change runtime type` like in the picture:

[image: runtime]

And then change it to GPU (takes some secs):
[image: GPU]